# Counting my array result

Tags: php, mysql

I was making a search box, and I want to count the result, i try to put count but nothing happens.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("concatenate", $con);
if($_POST['lname'] != '' or $_POST['fname'] != ''){
$searchq = $_POST['lname'];
$searchw = $_POST['fname'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet1
WHERE lname like '%$searchq%' AND fname like '%$searchw%' ");
```

I was hoping to count my result but i can't.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo                      "<tr>" .
                          "<td><b>" . $row['lname'] . "</b></td>" .
                          "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>" .
                          "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>" .
                          "<td>" . $row['telnum'] . "</td>" .
                          "<td>" . $row['network'] . "</td>" .
                          "<td>" .
                          "<select class = \"report\">" . 
                          "<option value = \"Wrong Number\" >" . 'Wrong Number' . "</option>" .
                          "<option value = \"Discontinue\">" . 'Discontinue' . "</option>" .
                          "<option value = \"Add Number\">" . 'Add Number' . "</option>" .
                          "<option value = \"Change Address\">" . 'Change Address' . "</option>" .
                          "</select>" . 
                          "<input type = \"submit\" value= \"Report\" class= \"classname \" name= \"report\">" . 
                          "</tr>";

 }
 }
```

Please help me guys

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't see anything about a count here.  Just add a `$count = 0` variable, and increment it every time inside of your `while` loop!

Comment: mysql_num_rows() function to get the count. Don't miss to see mysqli extension in php

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your query execution make sure that returns the result. It should not be 0.
You can check it by printing this line after mysql_query.

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result)
```

Hope you get your error.

Comment: Your welcome, Its good to give vote whenever you get help from other's answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

counting is easy just use `mysql_num_rows`. this method works for any `select` query. For queries using `update` or `insert` use `mysql_affected_rows`

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Also note that the `mysql` extension is deprecated. I suggest migrating to `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: Ahh, Now I know. Thank you for clearing that for me Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `mysql_num_rows`  for your select query

If you are using update or insert query then use `mysql_affected_rows`

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result)
```

or

```
$count = mysql_affected_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to count the number of rows of your search

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sheet1
WHERE lname like '%$searchq%' AND fname like '%$searchw%' ");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows ($result);
```

On a side note, remember to always check and [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your user input (the values in $_POST).

Comment: Ok sir, I will edit my codes. Thank you by the way

Answer (score 0):

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

mysql_num_rows($result) wont work in updated mysql versions

Comment: Ohw, i see. I look forward on it. Thanks anyway